# Realm, multiple instances from the same configuration

Tags: android, realm

In order to handle all the realm transitions, I've created an helper 'manager' class, that has the following property:

```
Realm realm;
```

Every method has a function that gets the realm instance from a configuration.

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
```

Where the the Realm Builder:

```
public Builder(Context context) {
    if (context == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A non-null Context must be provided");
    }
    initializeBuilder(context.getFilesDir());
}
```

In this way there are concurrency problems like '*this Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable*'.
I've written a test which writes/reads large amount of data but I am not able to reproduce the above said error, that occurs quite rarely.

What prevents me from removing the realm property and create a local variable per method, is:

- can a configuration be used to spawn multiple realm instances?
- if allowed, is this the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can a configuration be used to spawn multiple realm instances?

Yes.

Christian Melchior also does it himself [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1255#issuecomment-191371060)

> if allowed, is this the best approach?

That is a difficult question. "Best" depends on the situation and context. If you are only using 1 RealmConfiguration (you do not mention that you use multiple, so I assume you use 1), I suggest you define that in an Application class (as do the docs) and use `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` to reference it.